# Excel Vlookup Date - Create List with multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Good Morning,

I'm trying to make a list of all items done on a certain date Using Vlookup. Date would be on R8.
The first two highlight were place as an example of what I'm wanting it to look like.
Can someone help me figure out this formula please!

I tried this formula from a website I found but I cant seem to make it work.
=(INDEX($B$9:$B$150,SMALL(IF(R$8=$A$9:$A$150,ROW($B$9:$B$150)-2,""),ROW()-2)))

[image: Example of my spreadsheet]

Comment: First, fill in the missing dates.  Leaving those blank makes this incredibly difficult.   Second, if you have Excel 365, use `FILTER`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using office 365:

In cell `Q10` type:

```
=FILTER(B:C,A:A=R$8)
```

[image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/8z489VH2SHecgXwUA]